# onSaveInstanceState() not saving data from the intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a form. Here, the user fills in details like event name, description, location etc. To select the location, I have set a button. When I click on the button, I am taken to another page/intent. I select the location from there, and the location data is passed back to my original intent correctly. But the thing is, the data in the other fields like event, description etc. that users filled in are lost. I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189773/going-back-and-forth-between-intents-without-losing-user-entered-data) question before and tried those out. I referred to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) too and tried using `onSaveInstanceState` like this:

```
private static final String ENAME = "ENAME";
private static final String DESC = "DESC";
private static final String SDATE = "SDATE";
private static final String EDATE = "EDATE";
private static final String STIME = "STIME";
private static final String ETIME = "ETIME";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String name = etename.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(ENAME, name);
    final String des = etdes.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(DESC, des);
    final String sdt = StartDate.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(SDATE, sdt);
    final String edt = EndDate.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(EDATE, edt);
    final String stm = StartTime.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(STIME, stm);
    final String etm = EndTime.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putString(ETIME, etm);

    // Put (save) other values into the outState bundle...

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I have that function before the `onCreate()`; And here is my onCreate();

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventcreaten);

    etename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etename);
    etdes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdes);
    StartDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etstartdate1);
    EndDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etenddate1);
    btnCreateEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncreate);
    tvd2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvd2);
    tved2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tved2);
    tvg = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvg);
    StartTime = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etstartt1);
    EndTime = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etendt1);


    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        final String name = savedInstanceState.getString(ENAME, "");
        etename.setText(name);
        final String des = savedInstanceState.getString(DESC, "");
        etdes.setText(des);
        final String sdt = savedInstanceState.getString(SDATE, "");
        StartDate.setText(sdt);
        final String edt = savedInstanceState.getString(EDATE, "");
        EndDate.setText(edt);
        final String stm = savedInstanceState.getString(STIME, "");
        StartTime.setText(stm);
        final String etm = savedInstanceState.getString(ETIME, "");
        EndTime.setText(etm);
    } else {
        // No saved values to restore
    }
```

And it doesn't work. Can someone please point out why?

Comment: Is your activity extends Activity class directly or there is a chain?

Comment: @ruan65 yeah it extends Activity

Comment: Are you sure that `onCreate()` is getting called when you return from the other activity?  This Activity might not be getting destroyed, in which case `onCreate()` would not be called again.

Comment: @DanielNugent, hmm yeah good observation. But if it doesn't get destroyed, why aren't the previous data retained?

Comment: @YohanBlake  Hard to say.  Are you using `startActivityForResult()` to open `Map2.class` now?

Comment: @DanielNugent, I have this code as the onClickListener() for Map2 `Intent map = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Map2.class);
    startActivityForResult(map,1);`

Comment: It's really up to the OS as to whether or not it destroys Activities that are not in the foreground.  Here is one thing you could try, save off the values in member variables when you start `Map2.class`, and restore from the member variables in `onActivityResult()`.  Also keep your current code though, it looks like it would work if the Activity does get destroyed.

Comment: What's the rest of your Activity code? As a side node, I strongly suggest that you use common naming style for your variables (especially that they start with a lowercase letter).

Comment: @DanielNugent, you mean, send them as a bundle to Map2 and get them back from it and set the text views again?

Comment: @YohanBlake No, there's no need to pass them in a Bundle and then pass them back, although that would work of course. Just create member variables in your class, and assign the values to those member variables before you call `startActivityForResult()`.  Then restore the TextViews from those variables when `onActivityResult()` is called.

Comment: @DanielNugent, so I will assign the variables inside the onClickListener() of the button that calls Map2. I am unclear what you mentioned by the `onActivityResult()` thing. I am using an `onActivityResult()` to get an image from the gallery and to set it in an image view

Comment: @YohanBlake Honestly, none of that should be necessary.  Can you post more of your code?  There really isn't a problem with the current code in the question, so maybe having a look at the rest of it would give a better idea of what is going wrong.

Comment: @DanielNugent, here is my full class [EventCreateN.java](http://paste.ofcode.org/3aVYmSrr4GnHPFvARij9qkt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got it to work or not.  But I got it to work with this.

```
public class TestingForSO extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String ENAME = "ENAME";
    EditText etename;
    String name = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing_for_so);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            name = savedInstanceState.getString(ENAME, "");
            Log.e("NAME", "saved");
        } else{
            Log.e("NAME", "not_saved");
        }
        etename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etename);
        etename.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("NAME", "Saving");
        savedInstanceState.putString(ENAME, etename.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would run it in a seperate activity to test it out.  It must be an error in your code if it is not working.

Comment: I believe the code snippet is working. What I'm asking you guys is to help me figure out what's wrong with my code

Comment: Try getting rid of the strings in the onSaveInstanceState.  Just string the edittext into the value and test it. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Okay then, lets call Log.e("Called","onSaveInstanceState");  in saved instance state. Log.e("Called","Load"); in the onCreate != null. Let me know what is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78615/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-yohan-blake).